# Select dentro de select onde exista condição

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Bom dia,

Com uma tabela de artigos com os campos

> Referencia | Quantidade | Preco | ReferenciasAssociadas |

Pretendia ter um select que fizesse o seguinte, com o exemplo:

**Exemplo Tabela de Artigos**

> Artigo1: X - 2 - 1€ - A, B
> Artigo2: Y - 5 - 2€ - C
> Artigo3: A - 1 - 5€ - NULL
> Artigo4: B - 7 - 3€ - NULL
> Artigo5: C - 4 - 4€ - NULL

**Resultado pretendido da query:**

> Referencia | Quantidade | Preco |
>
> X | 2 | 1€ |
> A | 1 | 5€ |
> B | 7 | 3€ |
> Y | 5 | 2€ |
> C | 4 | 4€ |

Se a referência tiver referências associadas, cria sublinhas com os campos de cada referência associada. Como posso fazer isto?

Comment: Essa sua coluna `ReferenciasAssociadas` é um campo texto? Se sim o design da tabela já está ruim

Comment: Este é só um exemplo e não é o caso real onde vou aplicar isto, o design da tabela real não está desta forma.

Comment: Só que isso influencia na resposta. Você tem uma coluna só com as chaves ou tem outra tabela que relaciona os outros códigos?

Comment: Pormenorizando, tenho uma tabelar artigos onde tem as informações de quantidade e preço. Tenho uma tabela de referências associadas onde por exemplo existem 2 linhas (referência A e B). A chave estrangeira entre estas duas tabelas é a referência.

Comment: Beleza, isso facilita a resposta

Answer (score 1):

Considerando a seguinte estrutura:

```
CREATE TABLE artigos (
  referencia VARCHAR(1),
  quantidade INTEGER,
  preco      NUMERIC(15, 2)

);

INSERT INTO artigos(referencia, quantidade, preco)
            VALUES ('X', 2, 1.0),
                   ('Y', 5, 2.0),
                   ('A', 1, 5.0),
                   ('B', 7, 3.0),
                   ('C', 4, 4.0);

CREATE TABLE associadas(
  referencia VARCHAR(1),
  associada VARCHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO associadas(referencia, associada)
               VALUES ('X', 'A'),
                      ('X', 'B'),
                      ('Y', 'C');
```

A `query` para obter o resultado que você deseja seria:

```
SELECT x.referencia,
       x.quantidade,
       x.preco
  FROM (
    SELECT art.referencia AS aux,
           art.referencia,
           art.quantidade,
           art.preco
      FROM artigos art
     WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM associadas ass
                   WHERE ass.referencia = art.referencia)
    UNION
    SELECT ass.referencia AS aux,
           art.referencia,
           art.quantidade,
           art.preco
      FROM artigos art
     INNER JOIN associadas ass ON ass.associada = art.referencia
) x
ORDER BY x.aux,
         CASE x.aux
           WHEN x.referencia THEN 0
           ELSE 1
         END;
```

Na `query` acima vincularíamos os registros àqueles que são hierarquicamente maiores e ordenaríamos por essa relação.

Ou simplificando:

```
SELECT art.referencia,
       art.quantidade,
       art.preco
  FROM artigos art
  LEFT JOIN associadas ass ON ass.associada = art.referencia
 ORDER BY COALESCE(ass.referencia, art.referencia),
          CASE
            WHEN ass.referencia IS NULL THEN 0
            ELSE 1
          END
```

O resultado seria:

```
| referencia | quantidade | preco |
| ---------- | ---------- | ----- |
| X          | 2          | 1     |
| A          | 1          | 5     |
| B          | 7          | 3     |
| Y          | 5          | 2     |
| C          | 4          | 4     |
```

---

Você pode conferir o resultado no DB Fiddle [**para o primeiro exemplo**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ctLRtsy28XodwWMoU3iZXq/0) ou [**para o segundo exemplo**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/592GdBruTB4hytsxwk6nxy/0).

Comment: O que posso fazer quando por exemplo os campos em comuns são apenas a Referencia? Por exemplo a tabela Artigos tem os campos Referencia, Quantidade, Preco e a tabela Associadas tem apenas Referencia e ReferenciaAssociada. E necessito de fazer isto com uma CTE.

Comment: @DiogoFernandes Sua pergunta original já foi respondida com essa resposta. A sugestão que te dou é que aceite a resposta e faça outra pergunta explicando em detalhes sua nova dúvida.

Answer (score 0):

Eis sugestão que utiliza CTE não recursiva.

```
-- código #1
with ctePai as (
SELECT A.Referencia, A.Quantidade, A.Preco, A.Referencia as Pai, 0 as Tag
  from tabArtigos as A
  where not exists (SELECT * from tabAssociação as B where B.RefAssociada = A.Referencia)

union all

SELECT C.RefAssociada, D.Quantidade, D.Preco, C.Referencia, 1
  from tabAssociação as C
       inner join tabArtigos as D on D.Referencia = C.RefAssociada
)
SELECT Referencia, Quantidade, Preco  --, Pai, Tag
  from ctePai 
  order by Pai, Tag;
```

Para testar, utilizei a seguinte estrutura/dados:

```
-- código #2
CREATE TABLE tabArtigos (
  Referencia char(1) not null primary key,
  Quantidade tinyint,
  Preco money
);

INSERT into tabArtigos (Referencia, Quantidade, Preco) values
     ('X', 2, 1), ('Y', 5, 2), ('A', 1, 5),
     ('Z', 3, 2.1), ('B', 7, 3), ('C', 4, 4);

CREATE TABLE tabAssociação (
  Referencia char(1) not null references tabArtigos (Referencia),
  RefAssociada char(1) not null references tabArtigos (Referencia)
);

INSERT into tabAssociação (Referencia, RefAssociada) values
     ('X', 'A'), ('X', 'B'), ('Y', 'C');
```

Observe que nos dados foi acrescentada linha com valor de Referência ('Z'), que não possui subreferências e nem é subreferência de outras.

Comment: No SELECT quando chamamos o campo Referencia por qual é que ele vai buscar no CTE? É que no meu caso real, na tabela de artigos o nome do campo referência é "ref" e na minha tabela de associação o campo de referência é "refb"

Comment: Diogo, quando se utiliza união (UNION ou UNION ALL), os nomes finais das colunas são os mesmos definidos no primeiro SELECT da união (a não ser que na CTE sejam definidos nomes de colunas). Na CTE ctePai, a primeira coluna ficou denominada de Referencia, mesmo que no segundo SELECT da união seja a coluna RefAssociada.

Comment: O que posso fazer quando por exemplo os campos em comuns são apenas a Referencia? Por exemplo a tabela Artigos tem os campos Referencia, Quantidade, Preco e a tabela TabAssociação  tem apenas Referencia e ReferenciaAssociada.